# Building AspectJ app with ANT using build.xml

Tags: java, maven, ant, aspectj

I am having trouble building this application using ant.

So, this is my directory structure. All my files and the **aspectj** jar file.

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgg0A.png)

```
AspectProject/
├── AddCheatKey.aj
├── AddSound.aj
├── AddStrategy.aj
├── bin
│   └── aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar
├── build.xml
├── RandomStrategy.java
├── SmartStrategy.java
├── sounds
│   ├── cheering.wav
│   ├── cheer.ogg
│   ├── chip1.wav
│   ├── chip2.wav
│   └── wood_chip.wav
└── Strategy.java
```

When I use the command: **ant** or **ant -f build.xml** it gives me an error. Saying that the **aspectj** jar file does not exist. Even though it is in the directory tree!

[Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cShL.png)

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/Desktop/AspectJ-ConnectFour/build.xml:10: **The archive aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar doesn't exist**
```

[Line 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6eHx.png)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="c4" basedir="." default="jar">
<property name="ajrt.dir" value="\"/>
<property name="ajrt.jar" value="aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar" />
<property name="class.dir" value="bin"/>
<property name="jar.file" value="${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
<property name="main-class" value="c4.base.C4Dialog"/>

<target name="jar">
<jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${class.dir}">                <!-- LINE 10 -->  
<zipfileset src="${ajrt.dir}/${ajrt.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
<manifest>
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
</manifest>
</jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: What is your reason for using Ant?

Answer (score 2):

In your directory tree, you show `aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar` as being located in the `bin` folder, but in your code you point to `${ajrt.dir}/${ajrt.jar}`, which would resolve to `\aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar`.

Simply change your code to the following:

```
<zipfileset src="${class.dir}/${ajrt.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
```

Comment: Or alternatively create another directory such as _lib_ and use `<property name="ajrt.dir" value="lib"/>`.

Comment: Sounds like your code isn't present within `${class.dir}`